# AWS S3で静的WEBサイトを作ろうと思うのですが

Tags: amazon-s3

書いた記事を予め用意したテンプレート【記事名.html】にコピペしてカテゴリ別に分けたディレクトリの下にアップロードして記事更新をしていこうと思うのですが、この時一般的なブログサービスとの違いは

サイトマップ
フィード
PING

などの投稿した際に各自反映される更新システムがあるのですが、これらを静的WEBサイトに取り組むにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
サイトマップは週に一度独自で書いたものをウェブマスターツールに送信するとして、更新情報を反映させるというのはアップロードしただけでは行われないと思うのです。

Wordpressなどは一切使いません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

更新情報もまめたろうさんがhtmlを手で書いてUPする必要があります。
手で書く分の苦労はありますが、自動で生成される更新情報よりも融通が効きますよ。更新情報として載せたくない修正履歴などは載せなくても良いですし。